# Where is PIP installed by default with Python 3.7 for Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, terminal, pip

I am new to Python and looking to use to to create some cool solutions. The documentation says that `pip` is included by default with Python 3.4+ and I've just installed version 3.7.3 but cannot located pip as I was attempting to use it to install the `Requests` package for API calls.

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
```

So I can see in fact that version 3.7.3 of Python is installed, yet pip isn't? I checked both `Library/Python/3.7/bin/` and `Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/` and do not see any reference to pip.

The [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) states that you can use a `curl` command to get pip and then install it. I am new to the terminal and have never used a curl command. Also, I've read you want to keep your Python3 stuff away from the system Python version, so would I use the following?

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Try `which pip3.7`

Comment: you should be able to use `python3 -m pip install <whatever>`. If you installed Python 3.7 the normal way, then it should have it's own PIP

Comment: Awesome, so `which pip3.7` gave me the following directory `$ which pip3.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3.7`, so how do then use `pip` in the terminal to get packages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to signal that you are using Python 3 with `python3 -m pip .....` otherwise it takes the default Python 2

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
$ which pip3.7
```

which returned

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3.7
```

The purpose of my question was to find out if pip was installed so i could use it to get another package. It was, so I ended up doing the following with success.

```
$ pip3.7 install requests
```

which returned

```
Installing collected packages: idna, urllib3, chardet, certifi, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2019.3.9 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.3
```

I'd imagine that since I only installed Python3.7 on my mac and since pip3.7 was included, i could have likely input `pip3 install requests` although I am not sure if there were other versions of pip installed prior what would happen, maybe someone could clarify in comments about the nuances.